# Finding all functions satisfying $\int^x_0f(t)dt=f(x)-1$

Tags: integration, derivatives

> I want to find all functions that satisfy $$\int^x_0f(t)dt=f(x)-1$$

It's easy to check that $e^x$ satisfies this equation. Also, from Newton-Libnitz one can verify that the above equality implies $f(x)=f'(x)$, so I suspect that all solution are of the form $ce^x$.

Now, looking at the equation, only function of the form $ce^x$ to satisfy this equation is $e^x$. Is it really the only function to satisfy this property or am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. You can also say that$$0=\int_0^0f(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(0)-1,$$and that therefore $f(0)=1$. And the only function of the form $x\mapsto ce^x$ that maps $0$ into $1$ is the exponential function.